# Playing a video which is given in an xml file in web

Tags: html, css, xml, video, jwplayer

I'm working on a video providing website which works with an API and gets name, description and etc from the API using JSON. for preview page I should show a video which is sent by API but the link is not a video file. It's kind of xml like this:

```
<manifest xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0">
    <id>3_78.smil</id>
    <mimeType>video/mp4</mimeType>
    <streamType>recorded</streamType>
    <deliveryType>streaming</deliveryType>
    <media streamId="1" bootstrapInfoId="bootstrap0" bitrate="48"         
            url="media_b50000_w904626405_qd3ByZWZpeGVuZHRpbWU9MCZ3cHJlZml4aGFzaD1FZ1VvV1dJMVBpYWlBdU5pTUx1NFh5aFFHZlBkZ1VBQktxN0ZuUHI2eXMwJTNEJndwcmVmaXhzdGFydHRpbWU9MA==_tkd3ByZWZpeGVuZHRpbWU9MCZ3cHJlZml4aGFzaD1FZ1VvV1dJMVBpYWlBdU5pTUx1NFh5aFFHZlBkZ1VBQktxN0ZuUHI2eXMwPSZ3cHJlZml4c3RhcnR0aW1lPTA=.abst/">
    </media>
</manifest>
```

The guy who has developed this API told me to use JW Player 7 to play this and I did this but no result!
what should I do and what exactly is this file that I'm getting from server

Comment: Why not use html tag for videos? Did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Pablo as I said server passes a xml and <video> cannot play it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it might be an Adobe HDS stream. JW Player does not support this format.

See if you can get a copy of the same video in HLS, RTMP, or MPEG DASH formats.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I should seek  a HDS player or maybe make backend guys to do something about it

Comment: Either one - depends what's easier in your situation.